# Selecting parents of children who meet certain criteria

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So, I have retrieve a bunch of Countries from my database:

```
var countries = dbContext.Countries.toList();
```

Then, depending on program flow, I filter further on these Contries:

```
var asianContries = result.where(c=>c.continent == "asia").toList();
```

My Countries table is a "parent" table to a Cities table, with each city relating to a country. The cities table contains population info, which I further want to filter on.

I want, from the already filtered "asianCountries" list object, a list of countries in which there are cities with more than 500,000 people. I just went stone-cold in trying to figure out how to do it. Also, I'm new to this stuff.

Why this multistep-filtering instead of selecting on all criteria in one go? Complexity of program flow. Long story. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood correctly you have filtered to Asian countries already now you want to filter those results further.
I would do it one of two ways either if you have the population as int

```
var cities = asianCountries.Select(x => x.cities.Where( y => y.population > 500000)).ToList();
```

if it is a string then

```
var cities = asianCountries.Select(x => x.cities.Where(y => Convert.ToInt32(y.population) > 500000)).ToList();
```

This should work i think.

Answer (score 1):

Example for joining multiple tables ,

```
from ct in dbContext.Countries
          join ci in dbContext.Cities on ct.CityID equals ci.ID
          where (ct.continent == "asia") && (ci.Population == // yourCondition) 
          select new { country = ct.Name, city = ci.Name , // other fields you want to select
                     };
```

You could take a reference how to join multiple tables [here](http://www.dotnetlearners.com/linq/linq-to-sql-inner-join.aspx)

Comment: Would rather like to avoid joins and have EntityFramework take care of that, since relations are already defined in my Model schema. Also, I need to select from the already reduced asianCountries list object, not from the entire dbContext.Countries object.

Comment: @jjespersen , `relations are already defined in my Model schema` . Then @Haldo answer would help you

Answer (score 1):

If an object implements `IQueryable<T>` the query is only executed when the object is enumerated.  This means that you can chain queries together and execution will be deferred until you call, for example `ToList()`.

In your example you could do something like:

```
// to select the cities
var largeCities = dbContext.Countries
                           .Include(t => t.Cities)
                           .Where(c=> c.continent == "asia" 
                                  && c.Cities.Population > 500000)
                           .Select(c => c.Cities).ToList();

// EDIT
// to select the countries that have these cities
var countries = dbContext.Countries
                           .Include(t => t.Cities)
                           .Where(c=> c.continent == "asia" 
                                  && c.Cities.Population > 500000)
                           .ToList();  // remove .Select(c => C.Cities) if you want the countries
```

Or

```
var largeCities = asianCountries
                       .Where(c => c.Cities.Population > 500000)
                       .Select(c => c.Cities)
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: Problem is that the Population property is not accessible in line 2 of your second example. Solution found in answer below. :-)